# how to set a defaut using function uuid() in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to set a uuid value to "id" field via function uuid().
And I do not want to use as Trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
`username` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`values` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

the spec is quite explicit on this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

> With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

so either you use triggers, calculate the value beforehand (e.g. in php) or you use some other database, e.g. oracle might support it.